# Dynamic variable group for Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a release pipeline that run several stages:

- Create an architecture based on a ARM template
- Deploy an artifact on the web app
- Execute a Powershell script

I'm using variables from a variable group in these different stages. However, I'm wondering if the variable group could be dynamic. The idea is to be able to use this release pipeline to deploy on different environment. When triggering a release, I'd like to, somehow, be able to say "use the Production variable group" or "use the Acceptance variable group". This way, the same release could deploy on different environment.

For now, the only way to do this is to clone the pipeline and link another variable group, which is not optimal.

Is it possible ?

Edit

I found [this link](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/db/200.6x-Database-SetEnvVariablesandApprovalsinRelease.html) that explain that I can add environment for a release but I cannot find the option to add environment on Azure DevOps. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a different stage in your pipeline to represent the different environments for deployment.  You will either have to duplicate the tasks or create a [Task Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts).

[image]

When you link a variable group, you can scope it to the release or the stage.  Scoping to the stage I think achieves what you are asking for.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I figured this out a bit after having posted the question but thanks a lot, it was indeed the way to go.